# How do I use layouts and view scripts outside of controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a new class, not a controller, nor a model, nor a mailer, that will act as a sort of controller.

It will have a `render` method that will need to render an HTML view script and layout associated with this class.

How can I utilize what Rails already provides in my class to render these views?

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid Rails controller?

Comment: What do you mean? This object isn't a controller. It just acts similar to one.

Answer (score 0):

[AbstractController](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/AbstractController), specifically [AbstractController::Rendering](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/AbstractController/Rendering) is probably what I would look at first. There's likely something you can use there.